# Linking error with static methods

Tags: c++, linker

I'm unable to figure out what's the problem here. I have a `ConsoleIO` class, which contains two methods:

```
static void OutputMessage(const std::string &message);
static void OutputMessageNoNewLine(const std::string &message);
```

They are defined inline in the header:

```
inline void ConsoleIO::OutputMessage(const std::string &message)
{
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}

inline void OutputMessageNoNewLine(const std::string &message)
{
    std::cout << message << " ";
    std::flush(std::cout);
}
```

Also another class, `ContentParser`, with the methods:

```
static const bool                   StringEquals(const char *a, const char *b);
                                    template <typename T>
static const std::string            NumToString(const T num);
                                    template <typename T>
static const T                      StringToNum(const std::string &s);
```

Which are defined in a separate file, `ContentParser.cpp`.

```
template <typename T>
const std::string ContentParser::NumToString(const T num)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << num;
    return ss.str();
}
```

I have the following code in the `AdventureGame` class:

```
ConsoleIO::OutputMessageNoNewLine(ContentParser::NumToString(num+1));
ConsoleIO::OutputMessage(" - " + decision.choices.at(num).text);
```

The strange thing is, from the above, the bottom line works fine, but the top produces an error when linking (line 65 error). The `StringEquals` method also works everywhere.

Here is the build log:

```
14:03:02 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project AdventureGame ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -o AdventureGame.o "..\\AdventureGame.cpp" 
g++ "-LD:\\Program Files\\tinyxml2-master" -o AdventureGame.exe tinyxml2.o Main.o ContentParser.o AdventureGame.o -ltinyxml 
AdventureGame.o: In function `AdventureGame::ProcessDecision()':
D:\adat\eclipse\AdventureGame\Debug/../AdventureGame.cpp:65: undefined reference to `std::string const ContentParser::NumToString<unsigned int>(unsigned int)'
D:\adat\eclipse\AdventureGame\Debug/../AdventureGame.cpp:65: undefined reference to `ConsoleIO::OutputMessageNoNewLine(std::string const&)'
D:\adat\eclipse\AdventureGame\Debug/../AdventureGame.cpp:68: undefined reference to `ConsoleIO::OutputMessageNoNewLine(std::string const&)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I would guess that you didn't define them 'inline in the header' correctly. But since you haven't shown that code it's only a guess. Please update your question with the relevant code.

Comment: What if you change your top line to `ConsoleIO::OutputMessage(ContentParser::NumToString(num+1));`, just for test

Comment: I guess @john is right

Comment: @dzada He was, but in the other definition, the namespace is correct, and I still have the error...

Comment: I don't understand, you added the namespace and it does fix the problem ? If so edit your post to show the code you actually compile.

Comment: @dzada Apparently, my problem is "templates don't have external linkage", as said by HansPassant. But I don't really know what that implies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
inline void OutputMessageNoNewLine(const std::string &message)
{
    std::cout << message << " ";
    std::flush(std::cout);
}
```

should be this

```
inline void ConsoleIO::OutputMessageNoNewLine(const std::string &message)
{
    std::cout << message << " ";
    std::flush(std::cout);
}
```

Easy mistake to make.

Comment: Oh no, I just spent 20 minutes making this post, and it's the stupidest thing... Thanks!

Comment: First error is because templates don't have external linkage.  You must define them in a .h file.

Comment: @HansPassant So every generic method needs to be defined in a header? Or what does that mean?